# Swagger codegen swagger-jersey2-jaxrs with spring boot 2 /Spring 5 not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-codegen

Default jersey-server and other related jersey dependency jar that comes with springboot 2 and spring 5 is jersey-server-2.6 , however when i am trying to add the swagger-jersey2-jaxrs dependecy to my maven project the jersey-server dependency is overriden to jersey-server-2.25.1 . due to this my application is failing to start up with below error .

If i remove the dependency application is running fine .

Added Dependency

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
                <scope>compile</scope>
                <version>1.5.22</version>
            </dependency>
```

Error I am getting

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-03-01T08:10:03.918+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider.initialize(Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;)V",
    "path": "/helloworld/v1/service/hello"
}
```

My question is , what is the compatible version of swagger-jersey2-jaxrs with springboot 2 and spring 5 .Is there something wrong that i could be doing ?Has any one tried using swagger-jersey2-jaxrs with spring boot 2 and spring 5

Is there any other way to exclude/ override the jersey dependency that is comming from swagger codegen other than maven exclusion tags ? i have tried using the exclusion but it seem there are a lot of jersey dependencies .

Also another point I have observed is in my previous project where SB version was 1.5 the depedency is compatible and every thing was fine.

Stack trace i am getting is  after adding the swagger dependency is without swagger dependency it is working fine :

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider.initialize(Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;)V
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$4.get(ApplicationHandler.java:408)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$4.get(ApplicationHandler.java:399)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:340)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:789)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying for a while instead of Above mentioned **swagger-jersey2-jaxrs** dependency I used below dependecy and it solved the issue as below dependecy will not override the Jersey-server dependency hence my application is woring fine now

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.22</version>
                <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                     <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                     <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a glassfish server comes with swagger-jersey2-jaxrs library.

Remove the glassfish server from the dependency using exclude that should work.